# How to send data from Android app to Node.js

Tags: android, node.js, firebase

I have an android app with Firebase database in which I connected a node.js with Cloud Firestore. Below is the code in node:

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require('./ServiceAccountKey.json');
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});
const db = admin.firestore();


admin
  .firestore()
  .collection("email_collection")
  .add({
    to: "email-sample@domain.com",
    message: {
      subject: "Hello from Firebase!",
      text: "This is the plaintext section of the email body.",
      html: "This is the <code>HTML</code> section of the email body.",
    },
  })
  .then(() => console.log("Queued email for delivery!"));
```

I have tested it (manually) by running the server from the terminal and I received the email successfully.

Now my question is: how can I run the server from the android app? In other words, there is a button in the app, how can I make the user (when he clicks on that button) triggers the node with some data like email address and then sends email through cloud firestore?

Comment: I think you might be looking for callable cloud functions

Comment: @MosheRabaev Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. Please make it as an official answer so I can accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be looking for callable cloud functions